# Looping Components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, loops, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do a loop in ReactJS.

I have a database which has the following structure:

Courses (collection) -> testcourse (doc) -> questions (collection)

In the collection of the questions, there's a document for each question that has a field stating the question type.

I want my code to loop through each question, find the question type then output the component depending on what it matches.

Currently, it outputs the latest document and the component depending on the type, but I am not quite sure how I would loop this.

CODE

```
import './App.css';
import firebaseConfig from './firebase/index'
import { Component } from 'react';
import TrueOrFalse from './components/TrueOrFalse/TrueOrFalse'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import MultipleChoice from './components/MultipleChoice/MultipleChoice'


class App extends Component {

  state = {
    questionType: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let db = firebase.firestore()

    db.collection('courses').doc('testcourse1').collection('questions').get().then(snapshot =>{
      const questionTypes = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc.data()
        this.setState (data)
        questionTypes.push(data)
        console.log(this.state)
       })
    })
  }

  render(){

    let question = null;
    if (this.state.questionType === "TrueOrFalse")
      question = <TrueOrFalse/>

    else if (this.state.questionType === "MultipleChoice")
      question = <MultipleChoice/>

    return (
      
      <div>
        {question}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's only showing the last one is that you call this.setState(data) in every iteration of the loop. Therefore, it overrides each previous value. Instead, if you want all question types to be in the state, you need to save all of them in the state. Remove the current setState(data) call and place a new one like this,

```
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
...
})

this.setState(questionTypes);
```

This will save all of them into the component state. Next, you'll want to iterate over this.state.questionTypes (I renamed questionType to questionTypes). For example you could do this,

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.questionTypes.map(questionType => {
        if (questionType === 'TrueOfFalse') {
          return <TrueOfFalse />
        } else if (questionType === 'MultipleChoice') {
          return <MultipleChoice />
        }
        
        // you're missing some cases, so I'm just returning null
        return null;
      }}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!
This is exactly how I imagined, however, it is now returning an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null"

Comment: No problem. Most likely, this means that this.state.questionTypes is undefined or null. Make sure that you give it an initial value in state (empty array). Then also make sure you always give it an array value (never null). Also, verify that you changed the name to questionTypes (with an s) instead of questionType.

Answer (score 1):

I have very little insight into your data structure, however, the refactored code below may help you move towards a resolution. I made some assumptions. Let me know if you need any further assistance on the issue. Cheers!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';

// Comment out for testing purposes - see in code replacement below
// import TrueOrFalse from './components/TrueOrFalse/TrueOrFalse';
// import MultipleChoice from './components/MultipleChoice/MultipleChoice';

// Contants for conditional component rendering
const TRUE_OR_FALSE = 'TrueOrFalse';
const MULTIPLE_CHOICE = 'MultipleChoice';


// Assumed returned data from firebase to replace firebase actual data for testing purposes
const dataFromFirebase = [{
    questionType: 'TrueOrFalse',
    question: 'Are you alive?',
    responses: [{
        id: 1,
        response: 'Yes'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        response: 'No'
    }]
}, {
    questionType: 'MultipleChoice',
    question: 'What languages do you like?',
    responses: [{
        id: 1,
        response: 'Javascript'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        response: 'Python'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        response: 'Java'
    }]
}];

// Minimalistic assumption of your <TrueOrFalse /> component to replace the imported component of same name for testing purposes
const TrueOrFalse = ({ componentData }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    componentData.map(data => (
                        <li key={data.id}>
                            <label htmlFor={data.id}>{data.response}</label>
                            <input type="radio" id={data.id} name={data.response} value={data.id}></input>
                        </li>
                    ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

// Minimalistic assumption of your <MultiChoice /> component to replace the imported component of same name for testing purposs
const MultipleChoice = ({ componentData }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    componentData.map(data => (
                        <li key={data.id}>
                            <input type="checkbox" id={data.id} name={data.response} value={data.id}>{data.response}</input>
                        </li>
                    ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            questionDocuments: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let db = firebase.firestore();

        db.collection('courses')
            .doc('testcourse1')
            .collection('questions')
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    console.log(data); // Data from firebase
                    this.setState({
                        questionDocuments: dataFromFirebase // mock assumbed data from firebase for testing purposes
                    });
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { questionDocuments } = this.state;
        return (
            questionDocuments.map(document => {
                if (document.questionType === TRUE_OR_FALSE) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div>{document.question}</div>
                            <TrueOrFalse componentData={document.responses} />
                        </div>
                    );
                }
                if (document.questionType === MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div>{document.question}</div>
                            <MultipleChoice componentData={document.responses} />
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            })
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```